# How can you access the response body of System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, sendgrid

How can you access the response body of System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent?

I'm trying to use the SendGrid API to send an email and it returns an 'HttpConnectionResponseContent' object. How can I acutally get to the response body (string) or JSON?  I can't even see how I get hold of the underlying stream.

[image]

Comment: In the screenshot shared by you, the API responded with `BadRequest` implying one or more of the parameters sent were incorrect.

Comment: Yeah I know - but I'd like to read and log the underlying error as we have an intermittent problem. For my screenshot scenario I deliberately sent a malformed email address so I could write the error handling code.

Comment: `response.Body.ReadAsStringAsync()`?

Answer (score 7):

You can through this to get the content body:

```
response.Body.ReadAsStringAsync()
```

You can refer to [this](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#error).

Comment: This doesn't work if the content is binary.  It has a weird header like `--5e245b83-03a1-4c87-8a46-ee4218845593 Content-type: application/jpeg`.  How do I get the actual data without the header garbage?